# changing dynamic content using JQuery .on or .delegate where the selector is not the dynamic content

Tags: jquery, dynamic-programming, jquery-on, jquery-delegate

Everywhere I look for examples for delegated clicking, everyone assumes the button is dynamic.

Scenario: 
I have a list of div elements that get created dynamically. 
I have a button. outside of the list.

The button works on the list, until it refreshes dynamically. 
Can someone provide a working example, of refreshing dynamic content, where the click button is outside of the dynamic content?

Comment: How is the list being refresh, and what does the lsit look like?

Comment: the list is refreshed by ajax. it's pretty much a div after div after div. they have a class of .answer. of course there's many elements inside the divs. but that probably doesn't matter. the divs are created on the ajax php page and pulled in by ajax. the ajax inserts them into a parent div (replacing the old list).